Bootstrap-Vue Table: Chinese Column problem
My page has a table generated by b-table
                    <b-table striped hover outlined responsive selectable small
                             sticky-header="70vh"
                             head-variant="light"
                             class="bg-white"
                             selected-variant="light"
                             :fields="props.panel.data.fields"
                             :items="props.panel.data.items"
                             :per-page="props.panel.data.prePage"
                             :current-page="props.panel.data.currentPage"
                             :busy="props.panel.data.busy">
                    </b-table>

The page field and column is dynamic, in English's is OK, but in Chinese I have problem below

How can I fix it?
